# PHP Swiftmailer with Zoho smtp server not sending mail

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm using Swiftmailer on a Symfony2. I'm also using Zoho mail to host my mail server and I have configured Swiftmailer using the smpt details provided by Zoho, but it looks like something is wrong because the following exception is thrown:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host 127.0.0.1 [Connection refused #111]'
```

My parameters.yml file looks like:

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: smtp.zoho.com
    mailer_port: 465
    mailer_encryption: ssl
    mailer_user: my_username
    mailer_password: my_password
    mailer_authmode: plain
```

and my config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    port:      "%mailer_port%"
    encryption: "%mailer_encryption%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    auth_mode: "%mailer_authmode%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

I have tested the connection using telnet and everything seems to be alright:

```
root:/# telnet smtp.zoho.com 465
Trying 74.201.154.90...
Connected to smtp.zoho.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: it is odd that it tries to go to 127.0.0.1 instead of the smtp.zoho.com, does your config.yml import the parameters.yml as resource? and how do you construct your mail ?

Comment: The parameters.yml is correctly loaded, the db connection params are in the same file and it is working. This is how I construct the mail:

`$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Subject')
            ->setFrom(array('name@email.com'))
            ->setTo(array('name@email.com'))
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'Bundle:Controller:view.txt.twig',
                    array(
                        'data' => $data
                    )
                )
            )
        ;
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you parameters.yml is well loaded then i think i know the problem where it comes from, i think your webhost  doesn't allow ssl connection port 465, it refuses the connection thats what the error 111 means, try first to connect using TLS security with port 587. If you still want to use 465 try contacting your web hosting to check that port.

## Edit :

Remove the "" should fix it

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    port:      %mailer_port%
    encryption: %mailer_encryption%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    auth_mode: %mailer_authmode%
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Comment: The parameters.yml file is correctly loaded, the database connection is working properly and those parameters are in this file too. 

I am using the 465 port and SSL connection because this is the configuration that Zoho told me to use. I have also tried the TLS security with port 587 and it is still not working, same exception.

I think I'll try to contact them to solve te problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: it can be your web hosting firewall blocking that port maybe its not zoho, so contact your web hosting first

Comment: I'm using digital ocean web hosting, I'll try to contact them.

Comment: I have read [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/i-can-not-connect-to-smtp-servers-using-ssl) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/smtp-impossible) that Digital Ocean is blocking SMTP in some accounts. I have opened a Support Ticket in their website. Thanks for your help!

Comment: forget it i didnt saw that you already connected through that port using telnet, thats weird

Comment: This was their answer: "SMTP over IPv4 is not currently filtered on your account, but please keep in mind that SMTP over IPv6 is not currently available." Any idea what else can it be?

Comment: If the parameters were correct the error would say 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.zoho.com but in your case it says 127.0.0.1 which is weird, how do you know that the config is loaded correctly?

Comment: actually the swiftmailer assume you have a mailing server on localhost and tries to go to 127.0.0.1 because it doesnt know smtp.zoho.com

Comment: Well, I know the parameters.yml file is loaded because the db connection parameters are in the same file, and the db connection is working. The parameters.yml file is imported in the config.yml file, and in this file are both configurations (doctrine for the db and swiftmailer). But what you says makes sense, the exceptions says 127.0.0.1 and it should say smtp.zoho.com

Comment: what happens if you set the host directly in config yml without using parameters.yml host:      "smtp.zoho.com"

Comment: I have also tried to configure it with a gmail account and it is not working either! I think I'm gonna get crazy

Comment: ah i think the error was too simple maybe it was the " "  remove the " " swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%

Comment: I have checked it and that's not the problem either. And if you read the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html) they are using the "".

Comment: what if you try something simple without configuration just hardcoded to locate where the problem is : $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.zoho.com')
      ->setPort(465)
      ->setEncryption('ssl')
      ->setUsername('')
      ->setPassword('')
      ; then construct the mailer  $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport); $mailer->send($message);

Comment: @pserracomas any news on this topic ?

Answer (score 0):

Change mailer_authmode: plain to mailer_authmode: login.

Answer (score 0):

After trying with all the solutions (in my development and the production machine) I've tryied [PhpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It works perfectly.

I think the problem is in SwiftMailer's code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log into zoho and set up an application specific password.  You can find it under Security -> Two Factor Authentication.  Use that password instead of your account password.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Zoho Mail **does not offer IMAP/POP support anymore with their free plan**:

````
```
FREE PLAN
Up to 25 Users
5GB* /User, 25MB Attachment Limit
Webmail access only+. Single domain hosting.
```
````

*+IMAP/POP Support Available exclusively with the paid plans.*

https://www.zoho.com/workplace/pricing.html?src=zmail

Old free plans (registered before 2018???) seem to still have IMAP/POP Support Available

Source: https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/zoho-free-tier-pop-imap-activesync-no-longer-free